# Redirecting iframe video after video finishes?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, iframe, video

I'm trying to add a video to my site so that when the video completes, it redirects to another page on my site. I've looked at a few forums, but none of them do what I need them to in my situation. Here's the embed code of the video I'm trying to redirect...

```
<iframe src="//ihigh.volarvideo.com/sheldonclarkcardinals/broadcast/embed/95383?w=640&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" width="640" height="360" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the rest of the code as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `setTimeout` but the problem is that if the video is paused there will be problems

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" frameborder="0" width="640" height="360" scrolling="no"></iframe>

setTimeout(function(){
window.location = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
},56000); // This is equal to the lenght of the video
```

Answer (score 0):

Volar has a javascript [API](https://github.com/volarvideo/player-api) where you can listen to events. Add an ID in your iframe:

```
<iframe id="my-video" src="//ihigh.volarvideo.com/sheldonclarkcardinals/broadcast/embed/95383?w=640&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" width="640" height="360" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

and then include `volarvideo.js` in your page and call:

```
var i = document.getElementById('my-video');
var v = new Volarvideo();

v.on('onComplete', function() {
   window.location.href = "<desired url>";
}

v.connect(i);
v.play();
```